# History of employment while applying for a visa

Tags: immigration, canada, student-visa, application-status

While applying for the Canadian visa/permit, applicants need to fill-up [IMM1294E.pdf](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/pdf/kits/forms/IMM1294E.PDF) form.

In the **Employment**-section, it is written that:

> Give details of your employment for the past 10 years, including if
>   you have held any government positions (such as civil servant, judge,
>   police officer, mayor, member of parliament, hospital administrator.)

Now, suppose one/more of applicant's previous employers have low opinions about the applicant.

In that case, I have two questions:

1. Isn't it detrimental to the application-process to provide the complete employment history of the applicant?
2. If the applicant doesn't provide true/complete information, what would be the consequence in the long run?

Comment: Expatriates is bristling with people dealing with the consequences of lying, including lying by omission, on visa applications. Try searching for "ban".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is detrimental to the application process to *not* provide the requested information. You should always complete the visa application truthfully and completely. Take extra precaution to ensure that you have not omitted any information.

If you don't provide true and complete information, Canada may consider this misrepresentation. In such a case, your visa application is [refused](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/resources/tools/temp/visa/processing/refusals.asp) under section A40 and you are automatically banned from Canada for [five years](http://laws.justice.gc.ca/eng/acts/i-2.5/page-9.html).

> 40 (1) A permanent resident or a foreign national is inadmissible for misrepresentation
>
> (a) for directly or indirectly misrepresenting or withholding material facts relating to a relevant matter that induces or could induce an error in the administration of this Act;
>
> ...
>
> (2) The following provisions govern subsection (1):
>
> (a) the permanent resident or the foreign national continues to be inadmissible for misrepresentation for a period of five years following, in the case of a determination outside Canada, a final determination of inadmissibility under subsection (1) or, in the case of a determination in Canada, the date the removal order is enforced

... which means that if you get caught later, after entering Canada, you will be deported, and *then* banned for five years.